# Search over multiple tables, display even number of results or increase number of one table's result if others have less hits

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple tables/content types searched for a keyword and a fixed number of "result slots" for the autocomplete in the UI.

Let's assume there are 4 tables (persons,pages,articles,places) and 12 result slots. When a search returns 3 or more hits in each table, 3 results are displayed for each table.

I need an algorithm (preferably PHP) that increases the number of slots for a table when there are less than three results in the others. It should "fill up" the slots with results from the other tables as long as there are slots (and of course results) left

e.g.

person: 6
pages: 3
articles:2
places: 1

thanks!

Comment: do any of the tables have relationships?

Comment: Sorry, but here's not the place where people code for you. You should come back with your code, when you're stuck or have problems. We'll be fighting each other to help you :) But no one is going to write full code for you, you need to show some effort and research. As per http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

Lets say you have 4 categories A,B,C,D in the order of priority.

Fetch the number of rows of A,B,C,D

---

The function min(3,X) returns the smaller of 3 and X. Now do your initial allocation of slots by

```
Alloc_A=min(3,A)
Alloc_B=min(3,B)
Alloc_C=min(3,C)
Alloc_D=min(3,D)
```

The remaining slots are then:

```
Rem_A=A-Alloc_A
```

and so on.

---

The number of free slots are then:
free_slots=12-Alloc_A-Alloc_B-Alloc_C-Alloc_D

As for filling in the remaining slots, you can do it in proportion to the number of remainaing articles.  We can allocate in proportion by

```
Alloc_A+=round(Rem_A/(Rem_A+Rem_B+Rem_C+Rem_D))
Alloc_B+=round(Rem_B/(Rem_A+Rem_B+Rem_C+Rem_D))
```

and so on. For example if there are 4 free slots and there are 9 in B and 3 in D,This will allocate 3/4 slots to B and 1 to D. But this can get unfair if, say b is 10 times as large as D. You can cap the others as, say 3x the smallest one.